# Understanding wp_add_inline_style

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to get my head round the wp_add_inline_style() function in WordPress.

```
//setting inline css.
function my_styles_method() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'custom-style',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom_script.css'
    );
        $color = get_theme_mod( 'my-custom-color' ); //E.g. #FF0000
        $custom_css = "
                .mycolor{
                        background: {$color};
                }";
        wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_css );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method' );
```

I understand most of it but I am not understanding this bit:

```
wp_enqueue_style(
   'custom-style',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom_script.css'
);
```

Is this a dependency? or a blank css file so that code is written to it?

If its dependant then why? I just want to load custom css into the theme so it can be more customisable.

Thanks

Comment: Well explained at WPSE: [*Understanding wp_add_inline_style*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/108843)

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my own question is, its a dependency :)

Comment: @Rubens it was my post, my question was asking is it a dependency or a blank css file, I answered it, it is dependant on the css file.

Comment: That's right; I retracted my comment. My apologies for the inconvenient.